# How to run two loops at the same time?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, multithreading, scanf

I have been developing a very simple text game using Objective C and Xcode. It is almost done but I am having a problem, the **scanf** method stops the loop and asks for user input while I need the computer to be running the rest of the loop, the solution I came up with was running two while loops at the same time, one being the logic loop and another being a loop for user input.

I have been doing my research and it looks like using threads are the way to go, I just have not found a tutorial that will break it down for a n00b in Objective C (I am decent in java, I just have never worked with threads). If anybody could explain them or link me to a very broken down tutorial that would be great. Or if anybody has another idea I am open to anything else.

Necessary Code (The scanf I am having a problem with has asterisks on the line):

```
 while(running != 0)
    {
        if(gameState == 1)
        {
            if(timeToGenerateNum == true)
            {
                while(randNumber < 10000000)
                {
                    randNumber = arc4random() % 100000000;
                }
                NSLog(@"%i", randNumber);
                timeToGenerateNum = false;
            }
            else 
            {
                while(time <= 2500)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Testing");
                    time++;
  ******************scanf("%i", &userNum);************************
                    if(userNum == randNumber)
                    {
                        score += time;
                        time = 0;
                        timeToGenerateNum = true;
                    }
                }
                NSLog(@"Game Over! Your score was %i!", score);
                running = 0;
            }
        }
        else if(gameState == 2)
        {
            NSLog(@"To play, simply type in the number that appears on the screen.");
            NSLog(@"But be careful, you only have a short amount of time before GAME OVER!");
            NSLog(@"The quicker you type in the number the more score you get!");
            NSLog(@"Are you ready to start, if so type '1' and press enter!");
            scanf("%i", &gameState);
        }
    }
```

Comment: how do you need the loop to continue when the very next thing after `scanf` is a test on the var that is set by `scanf`? i think you need to look at refactoring `if(timeToGenerateNum == true)` to a function (lets call it `randNumber`) then you'd change `if(userNum == randNumber)` to something like `if(userNum == randNumber())`

Comment: @Tom Ingram I need the loop to continue because time still needs to be added, this game is timed... The code is not perfect inside the nested while loop because I have not got to test it because `scanf` keeps stopping the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to learn a bit about BSD (Unix, Linux) input/output to pull this off: replace your call to scanf with a non-blocking function you write to acquire input from the user's keyboard.

This function should immediately return whatever the user typed, or immediately return with a zero character count if she didn't type anything.

Read up on the select(2) system call, and keep in mind that keyboard input (standard input) is the first file descriptor, file descriptor zero.